# Gaps in custom body parts export for Daz Genesis 8 character

Tags: unreal-4, character, 3d-modeling

I am trying to attach a custom mesh to a Daz Genesis 8 character, and export it into Unreal Engine.

I use a custom script (namely: goldenpalace - NSFW); it exports both mesh and morphs... but it creates a small gap between the body parts. I tried different body parts, but it creates the same problem.

As far as I got, I found out if I am setting the "tools" option from "Geometry editor" to "node selection" the gap goes away, but then at the export it creates a duplicated mesh from the extra body part, and the morphs won't export at all.

How can I solve this issue?

Here are some images of the problem (not safe for work):

- [duplicated mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMKtc.jpg)
- [gap between body parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8aDn.png)